# strings comparing for the secret key in encryption and decryption android

Tags: android, encryption, public-key-encryption, string-matching

I'm encrypting and decrypting text using this code

```
public class Encryption {
private static String charsetName = "UTF8";
private static String algorithm = "DES";
private static int base64Mode = Base64.DEFAULT;

public String getCharsetName() {
    return charsetName;
}

public void setCharsetName(String charsetName) {
    this.charsetName = charsetName;
}

public String getAlgorithm() {
    return algorithm;
}

public void setAlgorithm(String algorithm) {
    this.algorithm = algorithm;
}

public int getBase64Mode() {
    return base64Mode;
}

public void setBase64Mode(int base64Mode) {
    this.base64Mode = base64Mode;
}

public static String encrypt(String key, String data) {
    if (key == null || data == null)
        return null;
    try {
        DESKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes(charsetName));
        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
        SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(desKeySpec);
        byte[] dataBytes = data.getBytes(charsetName);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        return Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(dataBytes), base64Mode);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public static String decrypt(String key, String data) {
    if (key == null || data == null)
        return null;
    try {
        byte[] dataBytes = Base64.decode(data, base64Mode);
        DESKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes(charsetName));
        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
        SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(desKeySpec);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] dataBytesDecrypted = (cipher.doFinal(dataBytes));
        return new String(dataBytesDecrypted);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

I'm trying to match the key what i placed for the encryption & before decrypting if both keys match decrypt the text otherwise prompt me the wrongkey here is what i'm trying to do

```
string a="sfdsfsjbgdfkbgdfkjbgk";//encrypted text just for assuming 

decrypted=Encryption.decrypt(key, a.trim());

encrypted=Encryption.encrypt(key, decrypted.trim());

if(a.contentEquals(encrypted.trim())){
//show the decrypted text
}

else 
{
//Show the wrong key
}
```

This is how i'm trying to do but when i put the correct key else statement executes 
and application stops on the if statement
can any one point me out what i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Have you tryed encrypting and decrypting the same key and the value returns the same?

Comment: yes it's returning the same value if i try to display in else statement.

Comment: Check for @Duncan's answer

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem. Here is a little [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that fails to demonstrate the problem:

(*Note: this would have been easier if the code sample you had supplied was also an  SSCCE*)

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

import android.util.Base64

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;

public class EncryptDecryptTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String key = "12345678";
    String ciphertext = encrypt(key, "foo");

    String decrypted = decrypt(key, ciphertext.trim());
    String encrypted = encrypt(key, decrypted.trim());

    if (ciphertext.contentEquals(encrypted.trim())) {
      System.out.println("decrypted!");
    } else {
      System.out.println("wrong key!");
    }
  }

  public static String encrypt(String key, String data)
      throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    DESKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF8"));
    SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
    SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(desKeySpec);
    byte[] dataBytes = data.getBytes("UTF8");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    return Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(dataBytes), Base64.DEFAULT);
  }

  public static String decrypt(String key, String data)
      throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] dataBytes = Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
    DESKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF8"));
    SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
    SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(desKeySpec);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    byte[] dataBytesDecrypted = (cipher.doFinal(dataBytes));
    return new String(dataBytesDecrypted);
  }    
}
```

For me, this prints out `decrypted!` as expected. Note that I performed my testing using standard Java (not Android), but I've tried to repair the code to execute on Android.

Some side comments:

- Your constant usage of `trim()` seems strange. It doesn't seem to achieve anything.
- You use `contentEquals()` when you can just use `equals()`.
- You specify `DES` as the algorithm, which leaves the cipher mode and padding as defaults. You really ought to specify both of those explicitly.
- DES is too weak to offer any security, so you might want to consider moving to a stronger algorithm.

Comment: Crashes if i insert the wrong key for decryption plus if i use the key length less than 8 it crashes

Comment: i've tried this ` try{
          if (ciphertext.equals(encrypted.trim())) {
      // show decryted msg
    } else {
    //   show wrong key
     }
     catch(NullPointerException e){
   e.getMessage(); 
      
   }`
atleast this code doesn't crashes at the wrong key?

Comment: @OsamaAftab Depending upon your cipher mode and padding, you may get exceptions when you decrypt with the wrong key. You'll have to catch those and display your "wrong key" message. I would recommend you validate the key size prior to reaching this function.